# UIAlertview title half hidden - objective c

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, title

I am trying to use the following alert when I click a row in a table. I do get the alert but the title is half hidden. Can anyone please let me know how to make the entire title visible ?

```
uiViewForVoteSelection = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please amend member's selection by selecting one of the options"] message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"No" ,@"Abstain",@"Not Selecting",@"Not Present",nil];
[uiViewForVoteSelection show];
```

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some constant string"]` - ***Oh God, why?***

Comment: There are many things wrong with this. Why are you doing `[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]`? Why you putting what clearly is a message in title? Why do you have so many buttons for a `UIAlertView`? And finally you have to many buttons for the frame so this why the title is half hidden.

Comment: The stringWithFormat is an amateur way which I've already changed it. The requirement is in such a way that I need to add those buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is not the title, even a title like "Please" will be partially hidden. The cause is the number of buttons you added to the alert. If you want to keep the alert you should provide a bigger frame. But I would like to suggest you the use of an actionSheet for this kind of UI.

You can use the following UIAlertViewDelegate method :

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    CGRect frame = <your_frame>
    alertView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to provide a bigger frame like increasing the height ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the title is far too long. You should pick a short title and provide that string in the alert message.

Comment: the title is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to completely customise alert view. I would advice you to stick with a smaller title and less no of buttons, more importantly if you use landscape orientation for iPhone. These many buttons won't fit. The buttons size and spacing is constant, so try with fewer buttons and smaller title.